# Simple files parsing and info extraction

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, parsing, factory-method

First let me describe the problem, we want to solve:

- We have hierarchical directories structure with different types of templates. Each type of templates is located in dedicated folder.
- Hierarchical structure can be located everywhere, right now we stores it on our local disc, but in the future it can be moved to bitbucket or something.
- For now we have these types:
  templates, which have .tf extension are 'trigger' templates and are located in 'trigger' folder.
  templates, which have .pf extension are 'process' templates and are located in 'process' folder.
  files, which have .bas or .py extensions are 'component' files and are located in 'component folder'.
  All folders are located in root folder, let's call it 'Data'.

Format:
'trigger' and 'proccess' templates are quite similar, with some small adjustments. Template itself looks like 'ini' file, but not exactly. As example:

```
trigger.tf

[Settings]
TriggerName=ActivatorTrg
IconFile=trigger.ico
Component1=File=x1.bas

procces.pf

Settings]
ProcessName=Archiver
IconFile=process.ico
Component1=File=x1.bas|Name=x1
Component2=File=x2.bas|Name=x2
Component3=File=x3.bas|Name=x3
```

As you can see, trigger can have only one component and processes can have several of them.

'Component' files have source code written in Microsoft Basic or Python. We want to parse these files and extract all parameter names, which used to call two methods: `GetConfigParameter` and `GetParameter`. As example:

```
...
strIntegration = GetConfigParameter("Integration","10")
strTriggerName = GetParameter("-TriggerName")
...
```

Here, we would like to extract two parameters: `Integration` with default value `10` and `TriggerName` with no default value, but with `Hidden` flag, what `'-'` prefix is indicated.

Solution:

As soon as templates can be located in bitbucket, local hard drive or something, we introduce `ITemplatesContentProvider` interface:

```
public interface ITemplatesContentProvider
{
    IEnumerable<string> Templates { get; }

    string GetTemplateContent(string templatePath);

    string GetComponentContent(string componentPath);
}
```

`Templates` collection returns all templates urls (in our case path to the template file on our local disc). `GetTemplateContent` returns content of .tf or .pf file and `GetComponentContent` returns content of associated component (Component1=File=x1.bas)

`ITemplatesContentProvider` was implemented by abstract class `TemplatesContentProvider`, which is used almost to pass same `TemplatesProviderConfiguration` to all template content provider classes.

```
public class TemplatesProviderConfiguration
{
    public string RootTemplatesLocation { get; }

    public string ComponentsLocation { get; }

    public string[] TemplatesSearchPattern { get; }
}
```

`RootTemplatesLocation` - in our case 'Data' folder. `ComponentsLocation` - 'component' folder and `TemplatesSearchPattern` - extensions '.tf' and 'pf'.

```
public abstract class TemplatesContentProvider : ITemplatesContentProvider
{

    protected TemplatesProviderConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    protected TemplatesContentProvider(TemplatesProviderConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (configuration == null || !configuration.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(TemplatesContentProvider)} configuration is not valid!");
        }

        Configuration = configuration;
    }

....
}
```

...and then we have concrete implementation like `FileTemplatesContentProvider`

As soon as 'components' can be written in Basic and Python, which used different syntax and correspondingly parameters will be extracted differently,  we have `ParameterParserFactory`, which implements `IParameterParserFactory`, which return specific parser through the interface `IParameterParser`.

```
public class ParameterParserFactory : IParameterParserFactory
{
    public IParameterParser GetParser(string referencedFile)
    {
        return new BasicParameterParser();
    }
}

public interface IParameterParser
{
    IEnumerable<TemplateParameter> Execute(string content);
}
```

Besides, as soon as templates can be rather .tf or pf, we also have `TemplateParsersFactory`, which accepts `ITemplatesContentProvider` and `IParameterParserFactory` as constructor parameters and construct `ITemplateParser` (not parameter parser) class dynamically based on `templatePath` extension:

```
public class TemplateParsersFactory
{

    public TemplateParsersFactory(
                ITemplatesContentProvider templatesContentProvider,
                IParameterParserFactory parameterParserFactory)
    {
        if (templatesContentProvider == null || parameterParserFactory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(templatesContentProvider));
        }

        _templatesContentProvider = templatesContentProvider;
        _parameterParserFactory = parameterParserFactory;
    }
    public ITemplateParser GetParserFor(string templatePath) {...}
}

public interface ITemplateParser
{
    Template Parse(string templatePath);
}
```

Each `ITemplateParser` sub class has base class `TemplateParser`, which as well accepts `ITemplatesContentProvider` and `IParameterParserFactory`. The concrete implementations of `ITemplatesContentProvider` and `IParameterParserFactory` are constructed in the system as singletons.

And then the usage:

```
var templatesContentProvider = new FileTemplatesContentProvider(
    new TemplatesProviderConfiguration(@"Data", "component", ".tf"));

var parameterParserFactory = new ParameterParserFactory();

var parserFactory = new TemplateParsersFactory(
    templatesContentProvider, parameterParserFactory);
parserFactory.RegisterParserFor(".tf", typeof(TriggerParser));

foreach (var templateInfo in templatesContentProvider.Templates)
{
    var parser = parserFactory.GetParserFor(templateInfo);
    var template = parser.Parse(templateInfo);
}
```

I feel a bit bad that I need to inject in `TemplateParser` <- `ParameterParserFactory`.

But in general any comments or suggestions?

Comment: If you could improve the formatting of the code it'd be great.